# validates_uniqueness_of scoped to multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using Validates_uniqueness_of with the :scope option, is it valid to pass an array of columns like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :x, :scope => [:y, :z]
```

As I want :x to be unique in the context of both :y and :z
If not then how could you achieve this? 2 validations one for each scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it's valid and your syntax is exactly the way to achieve it. See the [validations documentation page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002457) for more details.